# "Should" in the past?

Tags: modal-verbs, should

What is the way to say that something "should be done" in the past?

I know there is a "should have" structure, but it is used for situations, when something was to be done in the past, but it wasn't. E.g. "You should have called me yesterday. Why didn't you?"

So, would it be correct to say "It should have been done" in a situation when something was to be done and in fact it WAS DONE?

Comment: Not entirely clear: do you mean some equivalent of *It was the right thing to do*?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from - "It should have been done" and certainly "You should have done..." carry at least overtones of censure. However, "It should have been done" meaning "There was a moral obligation to do it" can be a mere statement of one's view on a matter, without an implication that someone has failed in their duty. "It needed doing" is the more usual way of saying it, and carries less hint of censure (if stated in level tones).

Comment: There's a (possibly Gricean) invited inference of non-occurrence with _should have_, as the OP points out. The question is whether it's cancellable, and I think it isn't. So the best solution for a perfective deontic necessity modal is to use the paraphrase for _must_, the strong necessity modal, which is _have to_, as Colin suggests. Of course, this loses the weak/strong necessity distinction between _should_ and _must_, but then there's already an added distinction with the perfective; adding complexity in one sense often loses it in another.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, that *should have* usually carries the implication that it didn't happen.

> It had to be done.

is what I would say.

Comment: But couldn't, "it had to be done", imply it *was necessary*, in the past, for this action to be completed. Not necessarily the action was performed and completed.  I would have said: **"It had had to be done."**

Comment: It depends on context. If you're in the middle of a narrative in the past, and talking about what a character is thinking, then _it had to be done_ would mean that there was a necessity, but the doing was in the future at that point, so it was not known whether it would be carried out. But in the normal case, looking from the present, _it had to be done_ implies that it _was_ done. (The implication might be explicitly overridden: _it had to be done ... but there was nobody to do it_). Your _it had had to be done_ is different - that's in the past looking back to an earlier past.

Comment: Thanks it's clearer now. Context makes sense of almost everything.